# Django dumpdata unable to serialize existing column

Tags: mysql, dumpdata, inspectdb

I'm getting bit trying to `dumpdata` from a legacy db i've recently did a reverse engineering using django's [`inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/howto/legacy-databases/)...
Other than this every query works fine. In MySQL workbench the column exists.
But when trying to export the data I get:

```
CommandError: Unable to serialize database: no such column: af_datper.locnac
```

Using `traceback` doesn't reveal any of my lines affecting (pasted here not to pollute http://dpaste.com/1DASN1V).

The model field already admits null values for that column and the column does exists in the database (among seeing it with the workbench, `inspectdb` wouldn't have picked it up...

I honestly don't know what else to do. Any takers?

Answer (score 1):

A bit of digging into your traceback, I see this:

> File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
>   line 64, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py",
>   line 323, in execute
>       return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
>   **sqlite3.OperationalError**: no such column: af_datper.locnac

From the SQLite [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html):

> If a schema-name is specified, it must be either "main", "temp", or
>   the name of an attached database. In this case the new table is
>   created in the named database. If the "TEMP" or "TEMPORARY" keyword
>   occurs between the "CREATE" and "TABLE" then the new table is created
>   in the temp database. It is an error to specify both a schema-name and
>   the TEMP or TEMPORARY keyword, unless the schema-name is "temp". If no
>   schema name is specified and the TEMP keyword is not present then the
>   table is created in the main database.

In short, sqlite doesn't support `foo.bar` as a column name, unless `foo` is the name of the database or one of `main` or `temp`.

Comment: Not according to your traceback, which is throwing the error at sqlite3's connector.

Comment: Allright, that's a hint. I'm using a custom router and this application is talking to mysql while auth is on sqlite... I'll remove that and migrate on mysql...